# Swift iOS -Navigation Bar won't stay Hidden even though I'm hiding it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Everything is happening programmatically. No Storyboard and The collection view's vc and the detailed vc are both inside a TabBarController.

I'm using a collection view and when I tap a cell in `didSelectItem` I push on a detailed view controller. In the DetailedVC I hide the navigation controller.  I called the below in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewWillAppear` both individually and cumulatively to try and keep it hidden:

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

When the scene first appears the nav bar is hidden. The problem is when I swipe down on the DetailedVC the navigation bar comes down from the top of the screen with a swipe and it doesn't disappear. I discovered it by swiping down by mistake.

I press the navigation bar's back button and it works even though it should be hidden. The reason I hide it is because I have a video that plays at the very top of the DetailedVC so I use a custom button to pop back to the collection view. I also hide the status bar (similar to YouTube) but that stays hidden.

The DetailedVC is a regular view controller and it doesn't contain a table view or collection view so I'm confused as to why it's letting me swipe down and why the navigation bar won't stay hidden?

The collection view cell that pushes the DetailedVC on :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let detailVC = DetailController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
}
```

The DetailedVC:

```
class DetailController: UIViewController {


    let customButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("< Back", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.orange, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
     }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

        // I tried all of these individually and cumulatively and the nav still shows when I swipe down
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}

@objc fileprivate func handleCustomButton()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@objc fileprivate func configureButtonAnchors()
        //customButton.leftAnchor...
}
```

Comment: does it have navigation controller as parent DetailController

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar yes. The collection view pushes it on with a navigation controller in didSelectItem

Comment: so collection view is embeded in navigation controller

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar that’s the only way it would be able to use navigationController?.pushViewController... if the collection view wasn’t in a navigation controller how would that work?

Comment: ok so try hiding navigation bar before you push.  in didSelectItem

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I tried that and it didn’t work. detailedVC.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true. I tried it with all 3 and it didn’t work

Comment: need to check on your side only i tried same way working

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar that’s very strange. Thanks for the help! 

Comment: set `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why when I was swiping down while inside the DetailVC the navigation bar became unhidden but I moved the code to hide it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and now it stays hidden.

To fix the problem I used`navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` and set it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // this one worked the best
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

And to set it so it can show back inside the previous vc which would be the collection view:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

I said it worked the best because I tried all 3 separately and of the 3 `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true` was buggy. For some reason even in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it was making the DetailedVC jerk up and down even though the navigation bar didn't reappear.

And `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true` worked inside the DetailedVC, the nav bar stayed hidden and the scene didn't jerk but when I set it to false in `viewWillDisappear` so that the nav bar would show inside the parent vc (the collection view) the nav bar didn't appear there.

Comment: I was messing with it for days, lmao, glad to have helped. Cheers!!